# Fetching a variable from another script

Tags: php

Using a drop down list I am selecting a data from a list :

```
<option value="R.K.Hospital">R.K.Hospital </option>
<option value="Sevabhai Hospital">Sevabhai Hospital</option>
```

Now Using this part of the code I am checking whether the seat is available or not :

```
$queryreg = mysql_query("SELECT available FROM hospital WHERE h_name='$hospital' ");
        $queryreg = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryreg);
        $a=    $queryreg;  

        echo '<span style="color:ff0000;text-align:center;">Available seats are , '.$a['available'].'  </span>';

        if($a['available']>0)
        {

            echo (" <form action='book_bed.php' method='post'><input name='submit' type='submit' value='Book Now' /> </form>"); 
        }
```

Now I want to book the seat if the seats are available...

```
<?php


include_once('connection.php');

include_once('available.php');


$hospital=$_POST['hospital'];
$username=$_SESSION['username'];

$date=date("Y-m-d");


if(@$_POST['submit'])
{
    $queryreg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `bed_book` VALUES ('$username','$hospital','')",$connect);
    echo'<span style="color:#AFA;text-align:center;">Order Has Been Booked !!</span>';  
}

?>
```

Everything is getting inserted in the database except the $hospital variable... I guess there is some implementation problem...The connection and the database is working quite finely so there is not an issue. If anybody can help I'll be thankful...

Comment: `echo $hospital`; Result ?

Comment: It's showing $hospital as output... I have tried this one also but the value inside it is not getting fetched, Harshit

Comment: Whats inserted in database ?

Comment: watch out the query... it's inserting username,hospital and date into the database  , Er.kT

Comment: your code is vulnerable to sql injection, use either mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 0):

In your form there is no any input for hospital

```
echo (" <form action='book_bed.php' method='post'>
<input name='hospital' type='hidden' value='".$hospital."' />
<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Book Now' /> 
</form>");
```

and on submit of it you will get value of it

```
$queryreg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `bed_book` VALUES ('$username','".$hospital."','')",$connect);
```

Comment: Thanks sir but nothing is getting inserted in the database :/

Comment: Please first print $_POST array, and confirm that you are getting all values

Comment: Ok it's done... Thank you sir for your valuable time :) , Er.KT

Comment: Great, so what was the issue ?

Comment: Might be some server problem. I have restarted the system and then it's working